# Time incarcerated

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query for spent more time incarcerated than not sorted from highest to lowest percentage (as decimal value in range of `0.0` to `1.0` [or more]) of life spent incarcerated.  With the output `name`, `city`, `age`, `years_incar`, `pct_incar`, and `pct_out`.  Where `age` is the number of years (as a floating-point number), `pct_incar` is percentage (as floating-point value in range of `0.0` to `1.0`) of life spent incarcerated, and `pct_out` (as a floating-point value in range of `0.0` to `1.0`) of the percent of life spent not being incarcerated.

```
create table data
(
    id integer primary key,
    pct decimal(5, 2) not null check (pct > 0 and pct <= 100)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE latitude BETWEEN 34.0522 AND 37.0454 
AND longitude BETWEEN -118.2436 AND -116.4378 
AND lower(city) like 'cali%';
```

This will cover cali, california and CALIFORNIA.

Comment: This Answer appears to bear no relation to the Question.  Can you explain this?

Comment: @toonice I guess the question has changed completely since I answered it. Don't know what the original question was.